# The sound still working with internet explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net

> I have task which play video when click on video image , it is working
>   well but when I click on close the sound still working on the
>   background only with internet explorer

```
<div class="video-container">
                        <asp:DataList ID="DL_Varoius" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>' Width="215" Height="160"
                                        AlternateText="Video" /></a>
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlModal" Width="400" Height="400" runat="server" Style="display: none"
                                    CssClass="modalPopup3">
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <uc1:FlashPlayer runat="server" VideoUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Media_File") %>' />
                                    <br />
                                    <br />

                                    <a href="#" class="ad_mun_font_r" id="btnCancel" runat="server">Close</a>
                                </asp:Panel>
                                <cc1:ModalPopupExtender TargetControlID="Image" ID="pnlModal_ModalPopupExtender"
                                    runat="server" Enabled="True" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="pnlModal"
                                    CancelControlID="btnCancel" DropShadow="true">
                                </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="btnYes" runat="server" />


                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
                    </div>
```

Comment: you close the browser or ?

Comment: @Steve when click on  <a href="#" class="ad_mun_font_r" id="btnCancel" runat="server">Close</a>